# Finding the sum of 3 numbers with 5 positive integer divisors.

Tags: number-theory

> What is the sum of the three numbers less that 1000 that have exactly
>   five positive integer divisors?

So I see that first since there are only 5 multiples, the number must be a perfect square. Then, I took a look at a few examples.

$\#1\text{:}$

$$2^2=4$$

$$\implies\text{1, 4}$$

$$\implies\text{2, 2}$$

4 then has 3 positive integer divisors.

$\#2\text{:}$

$$4^2=16$$

$$\implies\text{1, 16}$$

$$\implies\text{2, 8}$$

$$\implies\text{4, 4}$$

This means that the square of a square number has 5 positive integer divisors. There are many of these under 1000, so how come there are three? I am probably missing a point here. What is wrong with my logic? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your last conclusion is not right.  For instance, $256$ is a square of a square number, but has many more than five positive integer divisors.  Hint: prime number factorization.

Comment: Incidentally, there aren't that many fourth powers less than $1000$, but there are more than three.  So you do need to narrow it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall: The number of divisors of a number $n$ whose prime decomposition is

$$n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$$

Is $(\alpha_1+1)\cdots(\alpha_k+1)$ (Exercise: prove this statement), then, you want this number to be $5$ and each factor being positive you must have all to be one except for one of them that must be $5$.

$5$ is prime you can only express it as $1\cdot 5$; so if every factor is one, that means the exponent of that prime is $0$ in the factorization of $n$, and the factor that is $5$ tells us there's only one prime in the factorization and that the power is $5-1=4$ (solving for $\alpha_\text{something}$).

With a little algebra you get that $n=p^4$ for some prime number $p$, then, the only prime numbers whose fourth power is less than $1000$ are $p=2,3,5$ so the sum of the four numbers is

$$2^4+3^4+5^4=722$$

Comment: Can you explain how you got to that $n=p^4$?

Comment: @Max0815 Well, since $5$ is prime you can only express it as $1\cdot5$; so if every factor is one, that means the exponent of that prime is $0$ in the factorization of $n$, and the factor that is $5$ tells us there's only one prime in the factorization and that the power is $5-1=4$ (solving for $\alpha_{something}$)

Comment: thank you I see how you got that!

Comment: @Max0815 Glad to help! :)

Comment: I added the clarification part to the answer. Its useful to me. After the edit is accepeted, I'll accept your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The three numbers less than 1000 with exactly 5 factors are:

- 16 {1, 2, 4, 8, 16}
- 81 {1, 3, 9, 27, 81}
- 625 {1, 5, 25, 125, 625}

So the sum is:  722, just as Max wrote.

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking five positive integer factors, not five prime factors. So, why cannot we take 4 also, since it is a positive integer.
2 cube *4, 3 cube * 4

Also, multiplication of 2,3 5,7  is also less than 1000. Why are we not considering it.
Can someone help me understand what I am missing here ?

Comment: The number must have exactly $5$ positive integer factors, no more and no less.  That requires it to be the fourth power of a prime, as explained in Bruno Andrades's answer.

Comment: 4 is a positive integer

Comment: And it has $3$ positive integer factors, namely $1$, $2$ and $4$.  So what?

Comment: Since 4 is also a factor, then the  numbers less than 1000 with 5 positive integer factors are:
16 ( 2 pow 4)
24 ( 2 cube , 3)
32 (2 cube, 4) and so on

the list is big. I didn't understand why everyone is taking 2 pow 4, 3 pow 4 and 5 pow 4 as the answer when above 3 numbers are also valid for the solution.